# Apache directory root configuration

Tags: linux, web-server, apache-2.4

I have Apache 2.4 installed on a linux box running Red hat .

My question is simple:
Is the directive `<Directory>... </Directory>` equivalent to `<Directory /> ...</Directory>` to configure the document root?

Thanks.
Edit:
This my httpd.conf, I removed all comments:

```
ServerRoot "/test/ApacheFolder"


Listen 80

LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>


ServerAdmin you@example.com


<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>


DocumentRoot "/test/ApacheFolder/htdocs"
<Directory "/test/ApacheFolder/htdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>


    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/test/ApacheFolder/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "/test/ApacheFolder/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz



</IfModule>



ErrorDocument 400 "/test/error.html"

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

ServerName localhost

ProxyRequests Off

RewriteEngine On

TraceEnable off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|DELETE|TRACK|MOVE|PUT|OPTIONS)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}

SSLInsecureRenegotiation off

ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off


<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine On
    SecFilterCheckURLEncoding On
    SecFilterCheckUnicodeEncoding Off
    SecFilterForceByteRange 0 255
    SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly
    SecAuditLog logs/audit_log
    SecFilterDebugLog logs/modsec_debug_log    
    SecFilterDebugLevel 0
    SecFilterScanPOST On
    SecFilterDefaultAction "deny,log,status:500"
    SecServerSignature "Microsoft-IIS/5.0"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>  
  Header unset Server  
  Header unset X-Powered-By
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#Directory) tag is used as container to specify 1 or more commands/configuration directives that apply to a specific file system path to the specified path.  The 2 examples you have specified are non-equivalent.

The document root is specified with the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#DocumentRoot) directive.

In this case your document root is specified as : `DocumentRoot "/test/ApacheFolder/htdocs"`
and is the file system path of `/test/ApacheFolder/htdocs`

And the following is the `<Directory> ... </Directory>` section that applies to it:

```
<Directory "/test/ApacheFolder/htdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The section:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

applies to the file system path of `/`.

This is done so that all locations
are denied by default unless specifically enabled as is the case with `/test/ApacheFolder/htdocs` above.  Some more details on that are [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/security_tips.html#protectserverfiles).

Comment: So in this cas, the <Directory/> apply to the path of the root document(/var/www in my system) and the <Directory> apply to which folder ?

Comment: Can you post your config please?